# how to animate from left to right?

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J53cg/): This animates from right to left movement.But I need to use this animation from **left to right**.

Basically, I'm using this script:

```
    var counter = 1;
        var thisw = $('.btn.close').parent().outerWidth();
        var thish = $('.btn.close').parent().outerHeight();
        $('.btn.close').on('click',function(){
            counter = !counter;
            if(counter){
            $(this).parent().animate({width: '5em', height: '2em'},1000);
            } else{
                $(this).parent().animate({width: thisw, height: thish}, 1000);
            }
        }).click();//click trigger is added because on first click it doesn't animate
//the reason is it is not getting actual width and height value as it is set in em but with jquery we get px value.
```

I even think my script can be written as better than this something like using ternary operator. But I'm stacked on this.

**Question:**

1. So what's the better way to write jquery of the above code?
2. Is it possible to animate from left to right without using position absolute?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 div{   width: 50em;
        height: 50em;
        background: red;
        float:right;
        direction:rtl;
    }

    <div style="direction:rtl;">
        <div>click me</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for your question.

**Script**

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( !$this.is('.active') ){
        $this.animate({'width':'5em','height':'5em'},1000);
        $this.addClass('active')
    } else{
        $this.animate({'width':'50em','height':'50em'},1000);
        $this.removeClass('active')
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J53cg/2/)